# Deleting divs inside a row with certain condition

Tags: php, jquery, css, mysqli

I have this basic search system with articles in 'cards' as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6aAQ.png)
Some articles contain a picture and others don't.

I'd like to only display the 'picture-box' `div` when there's a picture in it, [instead of having a blank white space when there's no picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIEQ4.png.)
How do I only delete the 'picture-box' divs without an image inside?

PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM article ORDER BY a_id DESC LIMIT 3";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $queryResults = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($queryResults > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        echo "<a href='article.php?title=".$row['a_title']."&date=".$row['a_date']."'>
               <div class='article-wrapper'>

                    <div class='picture-box'>
                     <img src='".$row['picture']."' class='picture'>
                    </div>

                    <p class='text'>".$row['text']."</p>

                 </div>
              </a>";
            }
          }
```

CSS:

```
.picture {
    position:absolute;
    left: -100%;
    right: -100%;
    top: -100%;
    bottom: -100%;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.picture-box {
    width: 560px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

I tried this:

PHP:

`<img src='".$row['picture']."' class='picture' onerror="imgError(this)">`

jquery:

```
function imgError(img) {
    img.error="";
    $(img).parent().remove();
}
```

-but it deletes the 'picture-box' divs from all the articles instead of the specific one.

Comment: I think in the way you did it it's better to be removed from server-side instead. and also $('img') should be $(img)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why even create the div in the first place and be reliant on jQuery to clean up the mess? Just add an if statement to your PHP when originally creating the page and don't add the picture if there's no value.

```
echo "<a href='article.php?title=".$row['a_title']." date=".$row['a_date']."'>
           <div class='article-wrapper'>";

                if(trim($row['picture']) != ''){
                    echo "<div class='picture-box'>
                        <img src='".$row['picture']."' class='picture'>
                    </div>";
                }

                echo "<p class='text'>".$row['text']."</p>

             </div>
          </a>";
```

Comment: Added this below the while statement and it deleted the whole card missing a picture instead of just the div, did i do it wrong?

Comment: Yeah, did you try putting the if statement inside the echo? That's invalid PHP. So you'll need to close the echo and basically have three separate echo statements.

I'll update my answer with the full solution.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `$(img).parent().remove();`.